# grep for string and grep for another string

Tags: shell

I have file with the following contents:

```
abc
def
ghi
abc and xyz
oooo
1234
567
```

Now I have to search for "1234" and again search for "abc" immediate above "1234". here 1234 will be only one occurance but abc will be mutliple occurances and the postion of abc will be varrying, it could be 1 line above 1234 or multiple lines above 1234, we have to grep the first occurance of abc just above 1234. and once abc is grepped , we have check for existance "and". Or we can grep "and".
Please help me.

Comment: You question is incomplete. You have told us what you want to find, but you have neglected to tell us what it is you need to do with `"abc"` found before `"1234"` and later `"and"`. So we search and find those things -- then what?? (also, hint: pipe the results of `tac` to whatever you search with to reverse the order of the input file). What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to check the existence of "and" in that line , based on the existence , I have to add my logic

Answer (score 0):

You can't really achieve all this in one line but you can get the line number of the 1st occurrence by running `grep -n [PATTERN] [FILENAME]`.

I ran `grep -n 1234 file.txt`. That gave me the result: `6:1234`.

I then piped that command to `cut`. This gave me a sub-string containing only the line number for the occurrence.

At this point in thime the cammand looked like: `grep -n 1234 file.txt | cut -d ':' -f 1`. This gave me the result: `6`.

Now that you have the line number with the occurrence, you can `cat` the file, pipe it to `head` and specify the number of lines to view. You can then send that to `grep`.

At this point my command looked like: `cat file.txt | head -n 6`. The result was the first 6 lines of the file.

To validate that there was "abc and" you would run: `cat file.txt | head -n 6 | grep "abc and"`

If you get a result, that means the item exists, otherwise it does not.